# How to update counter variable in a for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, counter

Say I have a for loop that counts from 10 down to 1 with counter `k`. In the loop, when `k` becomes 5, I make `k=4`. When I output `k` in each loop, I expected it would skip the 4 like so:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 3 2 1
```

Instead I got all the numbers from 10 down to 1, it did not skip the 4. How can I make it so that it skips 4?

```
for k=10:-1:1
   if i==5
      k=i-1;
   end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot modify the loop index from within the loop in MATLAB. Your two options are to omit that that index value prior to the loop

```
numbers = 10:-1:1;
numbers(numbers == 4) = [];

for k = numbers
    % Stuff
end
```

Or you can use a `while` loop rather than a `for` loop

```
k = 10;
while k > 0

    if k == 5
        k = k - 1;
    end

    k = k - 1;
end
```

Or you can also do what @beaker has suggested with `continue`.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the loop variable is not really changing the loop. What you're changing is the value of the variable *for that iteration*. Instead, you can tell MATLAB to skip to the next iteration using [`continue`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html):

```
for k=10:-1:1
   if k==4
      continue
   end
   disp(k)
 end
```

Result:

```
 10
 9
 8
 7
 6
 5
 3   <-- skipped 4
 2
 1
```

<sub>Edit: I just realized that you wanted to skip 4 and not 5. Code has been updated appropriately.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Matlab creates an array when you call a for loop.  If you enter

```
i = 10:-1:1
```

You end up with

```
i =

10     9     8     7     6     5     4     3     2     1
```

I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
for i = [10:-1:6, 4:-1:1] 
    i
    <do some other stuff here>
end
```

this gets us from 10 down to 1 skipping 5.

Comment: This allows you to keep the variable for i around if you needed it in the future.  It's worth mentioning that doing it this way, and learning how the arrays work will likely save you some pain in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative method

```
NumbertoSkip = [4];
for k=10:-1:1

      if(~ismember(NumbertoSkip,k))
         disp(k)
      end
 end
```

The code checks if it the current k is present is not present in the `NumbertoSkip` vector it displays it 
You can skip any number just put it in the `NumbertoSkip` Vector for example if `NumbertoSkip = [4 5];`

```
%      10
% 
%      9
% 
%      8
% 
%      7
% 
%      6
% 
%      3
% 
%      2
% 
%      1
```